# Bootstrap-datetimepicker formatting doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap-datetimepicker from [tarruda](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I've seen this [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/bootstrap-datepicker/latest/bootstrap-datepicker.pdf) But when I tried to format it with `DD/mm/yyyy` it doesn't work it gives me `DD/02/2013`. I want it to be like `Mon Dec 02 2013`. Any help? 
Here is my code:

```
       <div class='input-append date' id='datetimepicker1'>
         <input name="bdate" date-format='DD/mm/yyyy' type='text' placeholder="Date"/>
         <span class='add-on'>
           <i data-date-icon='icon-calendar' data-time-icon='icon-time'>
              </i>
          </span>
        </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function() {

                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                  pickTime:false,
                  format: 'DD/mm/yyyy'
                });                                             
              });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootsrap datetimepicker use the MomentJS and here is the link to [Moment JS Doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Here is the correct code.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     pickTime: false,
     format: 'ddd MMM DD YY'
});
```

Answer (score -3):

bootstrap does not have a datetimepicker. This is jquery UI widget!
Look at this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
You format is not correct, try

```
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
              pickTime:false,
              format: 'dd/mm/yy'
            });
```

The format can be combinations of the following:

```
d - day of month (no leading zero)
dd - day of month (two digit)
o - day of the year (no leading zeros)
oo - day of the year (three digit)
D - day name short
DD - day name long
m - month of year (no leading zero)
mm - month of year (two digit)
M - month name short
MM - month name long
y - year (two digit)
yy - year (four digit)
@ - Unix timestamp (ms since 01/01/1970)
! - Windows ticks (100ns since 01/01/0001)
'...' - literal text
'' - single quote
anything else - literal text
```

Comment: Did you really visit the link that I have provided?